# How to arrange the obtained result's Array given Below, to get a desired result given below?

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop, foreach

I Have a query

SELECT classid, COUNT(*) as cnt FROM tbl_name GROUP BY classid

on Table

```
| id | classid | contextid |

  1       1           2
  2       1           1
  3       2           1
  4       1           1
```

this will yields me the result by the use of an inbuilt library function moodle as

```
Array
(
    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [classid] => 1
            [classcnts] => 3
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [classid] => 2
            [classcnts] => 1
        )

)
```

I need the result in an array in the form of

```
Array(
     [classid]=>[classcnts]

)
```

i.e

```
Array(
     1=>3,
     2=>1
)
```

So  how can i arrange the available array to find the required array.

I am working in PHP

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
foreach($arr as $k){
   $new[$k->classid] = $k->classcnts
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mann It Worked My BAD in Arrays, Suggest me ometihing to strethen my array logics...

Comment: cool. select as answer so this question doesn't get asked again.

Comment: After 2 mins time validations in SO